# Why nginx support back end connections in grpc not http2?

Tags: nginx, grpc, http2

Why does nginx not support http2 for backend connections in gRPC while gRPC uses HTTP/2 as the underlying transport protocol. Who can answer my questions and clear my doubts? Thanks.

Can I communicate with a HTTP/2 server using grpc_pass?